# Do I need the meta-key for vim?

Tags: vim, emacs, keyboard-layout, language

I'm looking in to learning emacs or vim.  I started out with emacs but found the need for a meta key to be a hassle, especially since I have a non-english keyboard layout on my macbook.

So far I haven't seen any references to meta in vim, so my question is: 
**Can I live without meta in vim?**

If so that'll settle the vim vs. emacs question for me, otherwise I'll just have to learn to live with some workaround.

Comment: Curious about this "meta key hassle": on all keyboards I've encountered, one of the modifiers on the left of the space bar has worked as meta key and that seemed convenient enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no internal key bindings that use the meta key in Vim, but—with some caveats—it can be mapped.

Answer (score 0):

NB: With vim, mapping to  is a real P.I.T.A. With gvim I naver had any troubles.